# Write a set of images to a Video file on Google Drive

Tags: python-3.x, google-drive-api

I have a folder containing multiple images, i want to write these images as a video file on Google drive. Is there any way to achieve this?

I cannot write the images to video file in local system and then upload to Google Drive, because of space constraint.

Answer (score 1):

The google drive api is a file store api.  It contains information about the files it contains and it will allow you to upload new files.  To some extent it can covert one file type to another.   For example it can covert an excel file to a google sheets file and back and forth.

The google drive api does not have the ablity to allow you to upload two images and have them coverted into a video.

You will need to encode the video locally on your machine and then upload the video after.